# Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection. startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-security

My App has a intent redirection issue. So after sometime, I managed to find out where the issue is.
The issue is

> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity->startActivityForResult

Which i use in broadcast Receiver in SMS Retriever

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver smsVerificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status smsRetrieverStatus = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

            switch (smsRetrieverStatus.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // Get consent intent
                    Intent consentIntent = extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT);
                    try {

                        startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST);

                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // Handle the exception ...
                    }
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                    // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

onActivityResult

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get SMS message content
                String message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                
                if(message != null && message.contains("is")){
                    String pass = message.substring(message.indexOf("is") +2).trim();
                    
                    mEtCode.setText(pass);
                }

             } else {
                // Consent canceled, handle the error ...
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: fixing intent redirection. It causes security issue. google gives a deadline to fix the issue. If you don't fix it the app will be removed from playstore I have upload the beta version after doing some changes. If it is approved correctly then i will answer the question myself.

Comment: Google is absurd with this trash. They flagged the `onReceive` of a BroadcastReceiver that has export disabled because it could potentially be hijacked for malicious intentions. Sounds like the security flaws are the idiots writing the API, not the developers using them as documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes to fix the issue. Now it doesn't show any vulnerability after uploading to google play. for more information visit [this link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555)

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver smsVerificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status smsRetrieverStatus = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

            switch (smsRetrieverStatus.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // Get consent intent
                    Intent consentIntent = extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT);
                    try {

                    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(consentIntent);
                         
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // Handle the exception ...
                    }
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                    // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

For Results.

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                Intent data = result.getData();
                
                String message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification

                if(message != null && message.contains("is")){
                    String pass = message.substring(message.indexOf("is") +2).trim();

                    mEtCode.setText(pass);
                }
            }
        });
```